# Using template metaprogramming to provide strongly-typed coordinate systems

Tags: c++, templates

I'm attempting to define a 3d 'Coordinate' class that is strongly-typed on a 'CoordinateSystem' parameter. Simplified version of the current mechanism I'm using:

```
class CoordinateBase {
    protected:
        double a, b, c;

        /* millions of constructors */
}

class System1 : protected CoordinateBase {
    public:
        double& X() {return a;}
        double& Y() {return b;}
        double& Z() {return c;}

    protected:
        /* millions of constructors */
}


class System2 : protected CoordinateBase {
    public:
        double& Lat() {return a;}
        double& Lon() {return b;}
        double& Alt() {return c;}

    protected:
        /* millions of constructors */
}

template<typename T>
class Coordinate : public T {
    public:
        /* millions of constructors */
}
```

This works, but I'm not happy with the amount of boilerplate involved at each level in the tree (no-argument/explicit values/copy/move constructors, assignment operators). I would like to preserve the ability to have different names for the coordinate axes for different systems.

Using something like the CRTP seems helpful; then I could have the members that store the actual coordinate values in the Coordinate class and use static polymorphism to get at them from System1 and System2. Unfortunately, I can't do this:

```
template<typename T>
class Coordinate : public T<Coordinate<T>>
```

Or, at least, the compiler won't let, possibly because I'm missing some syntax.

Another possibility I considered was putting all the enable/disable logic in Coordinate:

```
template<typename T>
class Coordinate {
    public:
        std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, System1>::value, double&> X() {return a;}

    private:
        double a;
}
```

But that's going to get rather ugly rather fast and puts all the unpleasant template machinery where innocent users of this class will see it.

I'm not sure what the best approach to this sort of thing are. How can I avoid having to define so many boilerplate constructors/assignment operators while keeping the interface I'd like?

Comment: Off-topic: have you seen Boost.Geometry? They try to achieve somewhat similar goals there.

Comment: Just had a look. Our problem space is more around transforming between coordinate spaces (including several that aren't in Boost.Geometry) than doing geometric calculations with the points; the different focus leads to very different design goals I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
class Coordinate : public T<Coordinate<T>>
```

The code above is not valid C++ because `T` is a type, but you're using is as if it was a `template`. This is also not CRTP - here's an example of proper CRTP:

```
template <typename T>
struct base
{
    auto& as_derived()             { return static_cast<T&>(*this); }
    const auto& as_derived() const { return static_cast<const T&>(*this); }
};

struct derived : base<derived>
{
    // ...
};
```

You could try using CTRP in this way:

```
template <typename T>
struct base
{
    auto& as_derived()             { return static_cast<T&>(*this); }
    const auto& as_derived() const { return static_cast<const T&>(*this); }

    double _x, _y, _z;

    base(double x, double y, double z) : _x{x}, _y{y}, _z{z} { }
    base(double v) : _x{v}, _y{v}, _z{v} { }
};

struct coord : private base<coord>
{
public:
    using base<coord>::base;

    auto& x() { return this->_x; }
    auto& y() { return this->_y; }
    auto& z() { return this->_z; }
};

struct geocoord : private base<geocoord>
{
public:
    using base<geocoord>::base;

    auto& lat() { return this->_x; }
    auto& lon() { return this->_y; }
    auto& alt() { return this->_z; }
};

int main()
{
    coord c0{1,2,3};
    geocoord c1{1};

    c0.x() = 10;
    c1.alt() = 22;
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MEDhrOswMo7445r4)

Comment: I didn't realise you could use `using`in that way. That's probably the piece I've been missing.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving the problem like this:

```
template<typename T>
class CoordinateBase {
    protected:
        Coordinate<T>* upcast() {return static_cast<Coordinate<T>*>(this);}
        const Coordinate<T>* upcast() const {return static_cast<const Coordinate<T>*>(this);}
};

class System1 : private CoordinateBase<System1> {
    double& X() {return upcast()->c1;}
    // other coordinates etc.
};

template<typename T>
class Coordinate : public T {
    public:
        /* Constructors */

    private:
        double c1;
        double c2;
        double c3;

    friend class System1;
};

typedef Coordinate<System1> System1Coordinate;
```

So sorta-CRTP but I'm relying on convention to make the static_cast<> safe instead of a template parameter and convention. I've elided some namespaces and things that mean CoordinateBase and System1 aren't very exposed to the public.

The advantages of this approach:

- Coordinate system classes just have the operations that coordinate system specifically allows (mostly getting the coordinates)
- All the constructors live at the top layer, so no need to define or `using` them in lower down
- There's a single class at the top of the hierarchy where I can define things for all coordinates (or some significant subset), like arithmetic operations
- Relatively safe. I can static_assert that Coordinate has been passed something deriving from CoordinateBase, I can keep all the systems in their own namespace with a name like 'Internal' so people aren't encouraged to use them, coordinate systems can be made abstract so that they can't be instantiated on their own, if you forget to add the 'friend' declaration it won't compile, and you can only access the coordinates via the appropriate coordinate names.
- Easy to understand.

Disadvantages:

- No real way to ensure that the static_cast in CoordinateBase is safe, other than convention.
- Friend declarations